# Div de validacion no desaparece

Tags: javascript, vue3

Estoy realizando un proyecto en vue3 y js y tengo el siguiente problema.

He ejecutado una serie de validaciones para que ciertos campos del formulario sean obligatorios. Cuando intentamos hacer un "submit", si no hemos rellenado algún campo obligatorio, aparece un div con los campos que faltan por rellenar. Hasta aqui todo bien.

El problema viene cuando se rellenan todos los campos obligatorios, hacemos "submit", pero el div con la alerta de los campos obligatorios no desaparece despues de realizar el "submit".

Es decir, si teniamos alguna alerta de "campo obligatorio", despues de hacer "sumbit" sigue apareciendo y no entiendo el porque.

Aqui mi codigo:

```
<template>
  <main class="page-new-pet">
    <section class="box-auth">
      <router-link to="/"
        ><img class="logo" alt="logo" src="@/assets/icon.svg"
      /></router-link>
      <h1 class="main-title">Nuevo animal</h1>

      <form ref="myForm" id="myForm" @submit="createNewPet" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group" hidden>
          <label class="form-label">Id</label>
          <input
            placeholder="id"
            name="id"
            type="text"
            id="id"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="id"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
          <input
            placeholder="Nombre del animal"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Url imagen</label>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="image_url"
            name="image_url"
            class="form-control"
            accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
            v-on:change="uploadImage"
          />
          <img class="preview" :src="image_url" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Localización</label>
          <input
            placeholder="Localización"
            type="text"
            id="location"
            name="location"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="location"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Especie</label>
          <select
            class="form-control"
            id="species"
            name="species"
            v-model="species"
          >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una especie</option>
            <option value="Gato">Gato</option>
            <option value="Perro">Perro</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Sexo</label>
          <select name="sex" class="form-control" id="sex" v-model="sex">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una sexo</option>
            <option value="Macho">Macho</option>
            <option value="Hembra">Hembra</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Tamaño</label>
          <select name="size" class="form-control" id="size" v-model="size">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona un tamaño</option>
            <option value="Pequeño">Pequeño</option>
            <option value="Mediano">Mediano</option>
            <option value="Grande">Grande</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
          <input
            placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento"
            type="date"
            id="birth_date"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="birth_date"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Estado en la entrega</label>
          <select
            name="vaccinated"
            class="form-control"
            id="vaccinated"
            v-model="vaccinated"
          >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Vacunado</option>
            <option value="true">Si</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <select
            name="dewormed"
            class="form-control"
            id="dewormed"
            v-model="dewormed"
          >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Desparasitado</option>
            <option value="true">Si</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <select
            name="sterilized"
            class="form-control"
            id="sterilized"
            v-model="sterilized"
          >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Esterilizado</option>
            <option value="true">Si</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <select
            name="microchip"
            class="form-control"
            id="microchip"
            v-model="microchip"
          >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Microchip</option>
            <option value="true">Si</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Historia</label>
          <textarea
            name="comment"
            class="form-control"
            id="bio"
            v-model="bio"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Estado</label>
          <select
            name="status"
            class="form-control"
            id="status"
            v-model="status"
          >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona un estado</option>
            <option value="En adopción">En adopción</option>
            <option value="Adoptado">Adoptado</option>
            <option value="En acogid">En acogida</option>
            <option value="Acogido">Acogido</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Personalidad</label>
          <select
            name="personality"
            class="form-control"
            id="personality"
            v-model="personality"
            multiple="true"
          >
            <option value="" disabled selected>
              Selecciona una personalidad (CTRL + CLICK)
            </option>
            <option value="Bueno con niños">Bueno con niños</option>
            <option value="Bueno con perros">Bueno con perros</option>
            <option value="Bueno con gatos">Bueno con gatos</option>
            <option value="Bueno en casa">Bueno en casa</option>
            <option value="Bueno en el coche">Bueno en el coche</option>
            <option value="Tímido">Tímido</option>
            <option value="Juguetón">Juguetón</option>
            <option value="Cariñoso">Cariñoso</option>
            <option value="Me gusta estar en compañía">
              Me gusta estar en compañía
            </option>
            <option value="Me gusta estar en compañía">
              Me gusta estar en compañía
            </option>
            <option value="Independiente">Independiente</option>
            <option value="Cauteloso con extraños">
              Cauteloso con extraños
            </option>
            <option value="Amigable con extraños">Amigable con extraños</option>
            <option value="A veces ladro">A veces ladro</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-new">
          <label class="form-label">Información adicional</label>
          <input
            name="info_notes"
            class="form-control"
            id="info_notes"
            type="text"
            v-model="info"
            placeholder="Información adicional"
          />
          <span class="inner" v-for="item in info_notes" :key="item"
            >Informacion adicional añadida!</span
          >
          <button
            type="button"
            @click="addPetInfo"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-new"
          >
            Añadir información
          </button>
        </div>
        <button value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
          Añadir animal
        </button>
      </form>
      <br />
      <span id="alert" class="alert" v-for="item in error" :key="item"
        >{{ item }}<br
      /></span>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import { addPet } from "@/db";
export default {
  name: "NewPet",
  components: {},
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      error: [],
      id: "",
      name: "",
      image: "",
      image_url: "",
      location: "",
      species: "",
      sex: "",
      size: "",
      birth_date: "",
      vaccinated: "",
      dewormed: "",
      sterilized: "",
      microchip: "",
      bio: "",
      status: "",
      personality: [],
      info_notes: [],
      info: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addPetInfo() {
      this.info_notes.push(this.info);
      if (this.info_notes) {
        this.info = "";
      }
    },
    createNewPet(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (
        this.name &&
        this.image &&
        this.location &&
        this.species &&
        this.sex &&
        this.size &&
        this.birth_date &&
        this.vaccinated &&
        this.dewormed &&
        this.sterilized &&
        this.microchip &&
        this.bio &&
        this.status
      ) {
        var handle_status_new = {
          vaccinated: this.vaccinated,
          dewormed: this.dewormed,
          sterilized: this.sterilized,
          microchip: this.microchip,
        };
        this.handle_status = handle_status_new;
        addPet(
          this.id,
          this.name,
          this.image,
          this.location,
          this.species,
          this.sex,
          this.size,
          this.birth_date,
          this.handle_status,
          this.bio,
          this.status,
          this.personality,
          this.info_notes
        );
        alert("Animal añadido!");
        this.name = "";
        this.image_url = "";
        this.image = "";
        document.getElementById("image_url").value = "";
        this.location = "";
        this.species = "";
        this.sex = "";
        this.size = "";
        this.birth_date = "";
        this.vaccinated = "";
        this.dewormed = "";
        this.sterilized = "";
        this.microchip = "";
        this.bio = "";
        this.status = "";
        this.personality = [];
        this.info_notes = "";
      }
      this.error = [];

      if (!this.name) {
        this.error.push("Nombre es un campo obligatorio");
      }
      if (!this.image) {
        this.error.push("Imagen es un campo obligatorio");
      }
      if (!this.location) {
        this.error.push("Localización es un campo obligatorio");
      }
      if (!this.species) {
        this.error.push("Especie es un campo obligatorio");
      }
      if (!this.sex) {
        this.error.push("Sexo es un campo obligatorio");
      }
      if (!this.size) {
        this.error.push("Tamaño es un campo obligatorio");
      }
      if (!this.birth_date) {
        this.error.push("Fecha de nacimiento es un campo obligatorio");
      }
      if (
        !this.vaccinated ||
        !this.dewormed ||
        !this.sterilized ||
        !this.microchip
      ) {
        this.error.push("Estado en la entrega es un campo obligatorio");
      }

      if (!this.bio) {
        this.error.push("Historia es un campo obligatorio");
      }
      if (!this.status) {
        this.error.push("Estado es un campo obligatorio");
      }
    },
    uploadImage(event) {
      this.image = event.target.files[0];
      this.image_url = URL.createObjectURL(this.image);
      console.log(this.image_url);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Que puede estar fallando?

Gracias